# Jest Snapshot error when using React.memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am creating a file using `React.memo` (React 16.6.1).
I use jest 23.6 for snapshot.

```js
// Work.js
import React, {memo} from "react";
const Work => (
  /* codes */
);

export {Work as WorkNaked};
export default memo(Work);
```

When saving the snapshot of a component rendering Work, it will render `[object Object]` instead of `<Work />`, which makes it difficult to maintain and debug later on.

```js
// Container.js
import React, {Component} from "react";

export class Container extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Work />
    );
  }
}
```

```js
// Container-test.js
describe("Container component", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Container />);

  it("should render contents with a proper slug", () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

So now we are forcing the name as follow:

```js
// Work.js
export {Work as WorkNaked};

const memoWork = memo(Work);
/* eslint-disable-next-line immutable/no-mutation */
memoWork.displayName = "memo(Work)";
export default memoWork;
```

which will render `<memo(Work) />` in our Snapshot.

Isn't there a better/cleaner/simpler name to get the container name displayed when exporting it using React.memo ?

Comment: I think you may want to dive in the `ShallowWrapper` and match the snapshot of the component itself.

Comment: No, unittest should only test one component. The test for Work-test will use WorkNaked, but other components that use Work (and other stuff) will only see the memoized version of Work, so he wants to only print `<memo(Work) />` in that component's snapshot.

It's annoying indeed that memo doesn't add the displayName by itself

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you ran into an [`enzyme` bug](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1875).

This [pull request](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/1914) adds support for memo, which should render correctly inside of snapshots.